# How do I stop Windows from stopping write access to an unmounted EFI partition on a disk that is not used by Windows?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, virtualbox, permissions, filesystems

Setting: The computer has two or more physical hard drives. One is entirely dedicated to a Linux installation, one entirely to Windows. Both can be booted up. The system is configured for EFI booting.

Windows is Windows 10 build 17763.379. Installed in Windows is Oracle VirtualBox (tried with 5.x and 6.x) with a Fedora guest that has raw full disk access to the disk dedicated to Fedora. Fedora can be booted in VirtualBox, as well, and operated without problem. Except when it comes to writing to the EFI partition of the Fedora disk.

Fedora will try to write to the EFI partition but the async write will be denied by the host, Windows. No amount of running VirtualBox as Administrator or using the System account changes this. No group policy setting seems to affect this and, as far as I can see, I'm the only one in the whole wide web that has asked this question.

**How do I stop Windows from stopping write access to an unmounted EFI partition on a disk that is not used by Windows?**

Note that this is a peculiarity of Windows 10. The setting worked perfectly under Windows 7.

Comment: Is the Windows fast startup feature (since Windows 8) disabled already? If not, that's your answer ;)

Comment: Windows fast startup was not disabled. Now it is. However, this does not solve the issue. Still cannot write to the EFI partition on the non-Windows drive.

Comment: If that isn't the bootable ESP then Windows - without fast startup and properly shutdown after disabling it, not just rebooted - shouldn't prevent access to it.

Comment: You are absolutely right. It shouldn't. But it does. Oh, and to be super duper clear, I'm talking about write access. Not read. It can be read without any problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only fix/hack that I have found was to use hybrid MBR and hide all from Windows (if there is a MBR, Windows is using it instead of the GPT). There are some limitations (the hybrid MBR doesn't stay in sync with the GPT and you are limited to only 3 partitions in MBR) in my use case was the best option. Linux is using the GPT, Windows sees only the partitions exposed by MBR and everybody is happy.

Comment: Thank you. I can try this. However, do you happen to have instructions on implementing the dynamic MBR (and explaining what it really is) afterwards?

Comment: Hybrid MBR not dynamic. You can use gdisk to create a hybrid MBR on a GPT disk. But if you don't know about it, maybe you should read about it first. The MBR in that case uses one of the four entries to protect the GPT and the remaining  3 to map 3 of the GPT partitions. This works with Windows because it uses the MBR and ignores the GPT and the EFI partition is hidden from it. The drawbacks are (AFAIK): 1. you can only make 3 of the GPT partitions available to Windows; 2. if you re partition the GPT disk you must recreate the MBR; 3. some OSes don't know what to do with hybrid MBR.

Comment: + but if you only use Windows and Linux it may be OK. On the how to: gdisk, use x option to extra functionality, from there use r option to recovery/transformation and there use h to make hybrid MBR. But, once again, please search info about this so that you understand what you are doing. This are advanced settings and are not to be regarded light.

Comment: My mistake. You wrote hybid and I read dynamic. Dynamic made no sense, hybrid does.

Comment: I have now finally used gdisk to add a fresh protective MBR on the existing GPT disk and have chosen to not include the EFI partition on the GPT disk in the protective MBR. This results nicely in a disk that is GPT for Linux and for Windows does not contain the EFI partition. More importantly, this solution works.